# Cannot access database after authencation enabled

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I'm using mongodb 2.6.1, Windows 7 64bit

I started *mongod* without `--auth` and create a first user using

```
db.createUser({
    user: "root",
    pwd: "xxx",
    roles:
    [{
        role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        db: "admin"
        }]
})
```

I restarted *mongod* again with this configuration

```
systemLog:
  destination: "file"
  path: "c:\\mongodb\\log\\mongo.log"
  quiet: true
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "c:\\mongodb\\data\\db"
  directoryPerDB: true
  smallFiles: true
  journal:
    enabled: true
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
  http:
    enabled: true
    JSONPEnabled: true
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

There was no errors, so the authentication has been enabled.

I started *mongo* using `mongo -u root -p --authenticationDatabase admin` but I got error message shown below.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
Enter password:
connecting to: test
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: not authorized on admin to execute command { getLog: "startupWarnings" }
```

I tried to use `show collections` but I got error message shown below.

```
2014-05-20T00:36:07.801+0700 error: {
        "$err" : "not authorized for query on admin.system.namespaces",
        "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:131
```

But when I tried `db.system.users.find()` I can display the user in the collection without any error messages.

I also tried `db.auth("root","xxx")` but I got the same result, I can display user but I cannot list available collections.

I have 2 more db which were imported from the older version, without `--auth` these dbs work just fine, but starting *mongod* with authentication enabled, I cannot display anything inside those dbs.

Please help, solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the username: root was created with `adminAnyDatabase`, which actually has no priviliges such as find action.

Therefore as I expected the *root* to be top level user, so the *root* should be granted as superuser using *root* role.

```
use admin

db.grantRolesToUser(
    "root",
    [
        { role: "root", db: "admin" }
    ]
)
```

Also the `adminAnyDatabase` should be revoked

```
use admin

db.revokeRolesFromUser(
    "root",
    [
        { role: "adminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }
    ]
)
```